# Setting Ubuntu proxy in Perl

Tags: proxy, perl

How would I go about doing this? I have a list of proxies and want to rotate through them, but I need to know how to set the proxy first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more details to your question, such as what are you really trying to do and what modules you're currently using.

If you're using LWP::UserAgent, which is pretty much standard, the docs have examples:

https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent#Proxy-attributes

By the way: this probably belongs on Stack Overflow.